# Validating podspec return "type 'Bundle' has no member 'module'" after trying publishing SPM to Pod

Tags: swift, terminal, cocoapods

My SPM works fine on xcode and when i tried publishing it to cocoapods it shows the following errors in terminal here's the
Command line : " pod trunk push "

```
error: type 'Bundle' has no member 'module'
error: type 'Bundle?' has no member 'module'
```

How can I fix this error?
thanks

Comment: Same issue here. The weird thing is, that building the package itself or via the SPM works. Even using `xcodebuild` is working. But when `pod` creates the project and tries to build it `xcodebuild` returns the error:
`error: type 'Bundle' has no member 'module'`

Did you find an answer in the last 9 months or did you just give up?